# Finding a user is Admin or Not with Decalarative Authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin, declarative-authorization

I have implemented declarative authorization in my blog app. Now I have three layouts each for an Admin, Authenticated User and guest user. So I need to check what type of user is using the app at a particular time. We have User model, Role model and Assignment Model.

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :login, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_ids

  has_many :articles
  has_many :comments
  has_many :assignments

  has_many :roles, :through => :assignments

  def role_symbols
    roles.map do |role|
      role.name.underscore.to_sym
    end
  end

  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.login_field = :login
  end

  def deliver_password_reset_instructions!
    reset_perishable_token!
    Notifier.deliver_password_reset_instructions(self)
  end

end
```

Assignment.rb

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

Role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :users, :through => :assignments
end
```

Any solution?

Comment: how exactly do your models look like? associations? Does one user always just have one role?

Comment: yes sure. I will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify your structure with this gem:
https://github.com/platform45/easy_roles
Follow the instructions on github and modify your models like described there.
It is really easy, just a few steps. You just need your user model, and that´s it!

Additionally I would reccomend the cancan gem (https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

easy_roles and cancan are a good combination to define roles and permissions quite easily!

Comment: No option with the present model configuartion?

Comment: Of course there is..but I think it will become a bit tricky. You could define for each role a method which returns true or false, e.g def admin? current_user.roles.include?("the admin id") end. similar for the rest of all your roles. you also could generate generic methods, e.g def has_roles?(roles_as_array) current_user.roles.include?(roles_as_array with some find magic). do you understand what I mean with a bit tricky? :)